# Underfull \vbox (badness 4543) has occurred while \output is active []

Tags: badness

I am using overleaf and I got the following message:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 4543) has occurred while \output is active []
```

I have no idea of what does it mean. It appears in the log after a figure:

Log output where the message appears:

```
File: figures/logo-etsit2.png Graphic file (type png)
<use figures/logo-etsit2.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/logo-etsit2.png  used on input line 325.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 36.67815pt x 56.9055pt.
[5pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.2}) 
has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.325     \end{enumerate}
                          </compile/figures/t.png> </compile/figures/TvsN.png>]
<figures/chi.JPG, id=167, 732.48656pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/chi.JPG Graphic file (type jpg)
<use figures/chi.JPG>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/chi.JPG  used on input line 360.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 366.24237pt x 188.20265pt.

**Underfull \vbox (badness 4543) has occurred while \output is active []**

File: figures/logo-etsit2.png Graphic file (type png)
<use figures/logo-etsit2.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/logo-etsit2.png  used on input line 364.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 36.67815pt x 56.9055pt.
[6]
```

I don't know if it is related to the following problem I see in the output pdf:

[image]

The spaces between each item are too big. If I write the same text in previous sections, where spaces are normal I get:

[image]

No other error I got than the previous message so I don't know if it is related with. I think not only items space are too big but also for equation environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE? How we can reproduce your problem? Please, provide a example of small complete document, which reproduce this warning. This warning only means that formatting of your document is not optimal ...

Comment: the message means that there is not enough text to fill the page, so LaTeX stretches the spaces. In general this happens because of some large object like a graphic or a tabular that can't float away and so has to go to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

By casuality I found the solution:

In the figure position options, I changed `[H]` by `[!ht]` and the error disappeared and spacing is again correct.

Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/chi.JPG}
    \caption{Chi-square}
    \label{fig:chi}
\end{figure}
```